# Post request from server to server is coming out incorrect

Tags: python, json

I have database server and I have a webhook receiving server. When I use my `/itgpalertadd` endpoint for a webhook from anywebsite it works. However when I try to make a POST request from my webhook recieving server to my database server, the logs show `none` making me think the json is not correct.

Here is a test client file I was using to try and send json data from `local client` to `webhook server` to `database server`

test client file:

```
import requests
import json

webhook_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'

data = {"Password Trigger":"Password Updated","Password Name":"super fake emailk","Password Url":"https://conglomo.itglue.com/1316532/passwords/4585688","Organization Name":"conglomo Systems, Inc"}

r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

This goes to the webhook server:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def itgluealertwebhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        json_payload = json.dumps(request.json, indent=1)
        requestlink = requests.post(url = "http://127.0.0.1:5060/itgpsqdbadd",data = json_payload)
        print(json_payload)
        print(requestlink)
    return json_payload
```

Results from webhook server:

> {
> "Password Trigger": "Password Updated",
> "Password Name": "super fake emailk",
> "Password Url": "https://alloysystems.itglue.com/1316532/passwords/4585688",
> "Organization Name": "Alloy Systems, Inc"
> }
> <Response [200]>

However when it gets to the database server, it says `none` in the logs instead of the actual json data:

```
@app.route('/itgpsqdbadd', methods=['POST'])
def itgluewebhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
        requestj = request.json
        f = open('flasklogs.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(request.json)+"\n")
        sys.stdout = f
        # sys.stderr = f
        fullpasswordurl = json.dumps(requestj['Password Url'])
        print("variable: " + fullpasswordurl)

        if fullpasswordurl=='""':
            print("we are going to delete this from the database as it has no url")
            itgname_str = json.dumps(requestj['Password Name']).strip('"').strip("'")
            print(itgname_str)
            connecttosql = sqlite3.connect('companies.db')
            connecttosql.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            connectioncursor = connecttosql.cursor()
            connectioncursor.execute("DELETE FROM ITGluepds WHERE itgname LIKE ?", (itgname_str,))
            connecttosql.commit()
            print("Removed from database successfully!")

        else:
            print("we are going to insert or update this record as the url exists")

            try:   
                itgname_str = json.dumps(requestj['Password Name']).strip('"').strip("'")
                passwordurl_str = json.dumps(requestj['Password Url']).strip('"').strip("'")
                itgpwid_str = str(passwordurl_str.split("/")[-1])
                itgcid_str = str(passwordurl_str.split("/")[-3])
                itglueapi = "ITG.8b4510ebdc267d8a0842f910da56c80b.aR7vulOblpgP-oeDAEiIpzeHU-027IOOuJ25XmJmWmV2vby-9QjbrjkwX7jiKktb"
                header={"x-api-key" : itglueapi}
                passwordlink = requests.get("https://api.itglue.com/organizations/" + itgcid_str + "/relationships/passwords/"+itgpwid_str, headers=header)
                passwordata = passwordlink.json()
                passwordusername = str(passwordata['data']['attributes']['username'])
                itgcompany_str = str(passwordata['data']['attributes']['organization-name'])
                connecttosql = sqlite3.connect('companies.db')
                print("starting password update")
                connectioncursor = connecttosql.cursor()
            
                sql_insertval = """INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ITgluepds (pwid, itgname, itgusername, itgcompany, itglueid)
                                    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) ;"""

                sql_insertvalU = """UPDATE OR IGNORE ITgluepds 
                                    SET pwid = ?, itgname = ?, itgusername = ?, itgcompany = ?, itglueid = ?;"""

                data_tuple = (itgpwid_str, itgname_str, passwordusername, itgcompany_str, itgcid_str)
                print(data_tuple)
                connectioncursor.execute(sql_insertval, data_tuple)
                connectioncursor.execute(sql_insertvalU, data_tuple)
                           
                connecttosql.commit()
                print(itgcompany_str)
                print(itgname_str)
            except Exception as Argument:
                logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
                raise
            

        return 'success', 200
    else:
        f = open('flasklogs.txt', 'a')
        sys.stdout = f
        f.write("aborted")
        abort(400)
```

If there is anything I am missing let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know you're writing to two different files there?

Comment: Does the `print(request.json)` show you a Python structure?  Why check for "POST" if that's the only option in `@app.route`?

Comment: OMG - I realized I wrote this question wrong!!! That isn't even the right endpoint! GEEZ SMH. I am such an idiot. I am taking down the post and will edit it. Thanks for catching that

Comment: @TimRoberts I fixed the question. Also `print(request.json)` is what the webhook results show in the post above where it gives the full json structure before being sent off to my database server.

Comment: So where do you get the "None"?

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't why its coming up as `none` but it comes up on the database server when printing `print(request.json)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, although I am not sure as of why yet.

I changed my webhook receiver server to have this for the post request instead:

```
@app.route('/itgps', methods=['POST'])
def itgluealertwebhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = open('flasklogs.txt', 'a')
        sys.stdout = f
        json_payload = request.json
        requestlink = requests.post(url = "http://127.0.0.1:5060/itgpsqdbadd",data = json.dumps(json_payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        print(json_payload)
        print(requestlink)
    return json_payload
```

basically I performed the `json.dumps` method on my payload within side the `requests.post`